# Is there more than GET or POST for HTTP?

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I'm learning about writing Apache modules for a project I'm working on. I found the [official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/), which turns out to be *very* informative.

On the first page, "[Developing modules for the Apache HTTP Server 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html)", the section "Building a handler", subsection "The `request_rec` structure" provides some example code:

```
static int example_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    /* Set the appropriate content type */
    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html");

    /* Print out the IP address of the client connecting to us: */
    ap_rprintf(r, "<h2>Hello, %s!</h2>", r->useragent_ip);

    /* If we were reached through a GET or a POST request, be happy, else sad. */
    if ( !strcmp(r->method, "POST") || !strcmp(r->method, "GET") ) {
        ap_rputs("You used a GET or a POST method, that makes us happy!<br/>", r);
    }
    else {
        ap_rputs("You did not use POST or GET, that makes us sad :(<br/>", r);
    }

    /* Lastly, if there was a query string, let's print that too! */
    if (r->args) {
        ap_rprintf(r, "Your query string was: %s", r->args);
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Something that caught my eye was the `strcmp` on `r->method` to see if it's `POST`, `GET`, or *something else*. That's weird. I thought the only HTTP methods were `GET` and `POST`? Is there something else, or just the developers (or documentors) being unneedingly cautious?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of common methods is defined is [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9).

- OPTIONS
- GET
- HEAD
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE
- TRACE
- CONNECT

But there are many additional methods used by other protocols. For example the [WEBDAV protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-8) defines all of these:

- PROPFIND
- PROPPATCH
- MKCOL
- COPY
- MOVE
- LOCK
- UNLOCK

There is a [draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-method-registrations-11#appendix-A) with a list of all the known extension methods. But in the future it is expected that new methods will be registered with the IANA in the HTTP method registry as described [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22#section-8.1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are.

```
OPTIONS Request options of a Web page
GET     Request to read a Web page
HEAD    Request to read a Web page
PUT     Request to write a Web page
POST    Append to a named resource (e.g. a Web page)
DELETE  Remove the Web page
LINK    Connects two existing resources
UNLINK  Breaks an existing connection between two resources
```

For a full reference check the [HTTP Specification (RFC2616, Chapter 5.1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.1)